# City name too long for USA passport application

Tags: usa, passports

I'm attempting to fill out the DS-11 form, but the online and physical versions city column is too short. There are not enough blocks/spaces for my city address. Any ideas on what I am supposed to do? I didn't find any resources online to assist me.

Comment: Can you add the city name and the number of blocks/spaces on the form? (just because I'm curious lol)

Comment: @PeterM I should have included that, sorry! The form allows for 15 characters, but my city name is 20 characters. It's 3 words so it's pretty lengthy.

Comment: *Residents of the French town of Saint-Quentin-la-Motte-Croix-au-Bailly are currently unable to receive ID cards with the correct name of their place of residence. [...] For the time being, the residents are being issued temporary ID cards with an abbreviated place name* https://newsrnd.com/life/2021-10-14-france--place-name-too-long---residents-are-waiting-for-identity-cards.r1lJ62HHF.html

Comment: Are there any recognized abbreviations for your city (e.g. by the postal service)?

Comment: @PeterM: You want long place names? Take a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_long_place_names)!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the Executive Summary Review of the I-765:

[image]
Transcription:

> **Student Related Questions (Length of name, Degree, etc.):**
>
> **5. Most of our students are from India and Latin America have long names that do not fit in that space (oftentimes, even half of the name doesn't fit there). Where should these students put there full name?**
>
> **Response:** USCIS systems allow 30 characters each for Family Name (Last Name), Given Name (First Name), and Middle Name fields. While we understand there may be people with longer names, our system can only accept 30 characters. If the student's full name will not fit in the field, please put as much of the name as possible in the field, and also provide the full name on a continuation sheet.
>
> **6. We have a similar problem with Item 3. The full address often doesn't fit in the space provided, especially when a student needs to add "c/o".**
>
> **Response:** If the student's address will not fit in the correct field, please put as much of the address as possible in the field, and also provide the full address on a continuation sheet.

It seems logical you'd put in as much as possible, and if not clear, include extra information.

Comment: It should be noted that I-765 is a form used for non-citizens to apply for employment authorization and is not related to passport application; it's an entirely separate government department (Homeland Security versus State).  It's reasonable to guess that they follow similar rules, but this isn't a 100% answer to the question.

Comment: @NateEldredge It is more than good enough and commonsensical. He can’t hack into the system and increase the character count.